# html - How to open/start a BAT/VBS file

Tags: html, batch-file, vbscript

I have this certain vbs/batch file. I want to open it with html.
1. Can I start the file only on my computer
or
2. Can I have the html file create a batch file with the code:

```
@echo off
call use.bat %usage%
set num=%usage%
del use.bat
echo set /a usage=%num%+1 >use.bat
exit
```

Thank You! BTW: If I'm not too specific let me know. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `<script type="text/vbscript">` to enclose the VBS code. However, this might only work in older versions of IE.

References:

http://www.csidata.com/custserv/onlinehelp/vbsdocs/vbs9.htm

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-execute-an-external-vbs-vbscript-from-HTML-page

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon because links can become broken. Please try to summarize the relevant portions of what is found within the link here. The user can go to that link for more information if need be.